# Javascript variable in a variable name

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

If possible, how can I declare these variables in a less redundant manner?

```
   var number1 = 1;
   var number2 = 2;
   var number3 = 3;
   var number4 = 4;
   var number5 = 5;
   var number6 = 6;
   var number7 = 7;
   var number8 = 8;
   var number9 = 9;
   var number10 = 10;
```

The most logical code I could come up with is as follows:

```
  for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      var "number"+i = i;
    }
```

Comment: You could store them in a map or object, but no, that doesn't work. What are you trying to accomplish? Sounds like there's a better way.

Comment: this is off interest, handling this set of variables will be as complicated as being able to hypothetically create them in this way. use an Object.

Comment: Have you considered using an array? `numbers = []` and then `numbers[i] = i`.